# gZip compression/decompression in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, gzip

We are using gZip to compress/decompress of the response received from the web api. Below is our implementation.

```
[Route("Location")]
    [HttpGet]
    [DeflateCompression]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DisplayLocation>> GetLocation(string searchTerm = null, string impersonationUserId = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<DisplayLocation> locations= await DisplayLocationServer.GetLocation(searchTerm, WebUser);
        return locations;
    }
```

and OnActionExecuted method Added compression logic

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actContext)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> acceptedEncoding =
            GetAcceptedEncodingFromHeader(actContext.Request);
        if(acceptedEncoding != null && acceptedEncoding.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            HttpContent content = actContext.Response.Content;
            byte[] bytes = content?.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            byte[] zlibbedContent = bytes == null ? new byte[0] :
            CompressionHelper.DeflateByte(bytes);
            actContext.Response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(zlibbedContent);
            actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(actContext);
    }

private IEnumerable<string> GetAcceptedEncodingFromHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> headerValues = new List<string>();
        if(request.Headers != null)
        {
            request.Headers.TryGetValues("Accept-Encoding", out headerValues);
        }

        return headerValues;
    }
```

Till this compression logic it works fine. However, when we try to return the response from api side to UI it gives the error.

We are using swagger to consume web api which auto generates code and from that code request/response done. The response will be send to UI from auto generated code.

Below is the auto generated code where content will be deserialize returned from actual api method.

```
String _responseContent = await _httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            try
            {
                _result.Body = Microsoft.Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.IList<DisplayLocation>>(_responseContent, this.Client.DeserializationSettings);
            }
            catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException ex)
            {
                _httpRequest.Dispose();
                if (_httpResponse != null)
                {
                    _httpResponse.Dispose();
                }
                throw new Microsoft.Rest.SerializationException("Unable to deserialize the response.", _responseContent, ex);
            }
```

As the content is in zipped format, the response is not getting deserialized properly.

So my question is how can we zip the content/response properly which will work with this code ?

Also, we cannot do changes in auto generated code as it can be auto generated again in future so manual changes will be lost.

In short, we are trying to get the compressed content on UI side and will write decompress logic there. But because of swagger/auto generated code it is failing at that point only.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Is that httpclient configured to handle gzip/deflate?

Comment: @rene Nope. Is this related to my issue ? can you tell me how we can configure that ?

Comment: @rene if it wasn't configured for compression, then it shouldn't be sending `Accept-Encoding`...

Comment: @rene But still i will be facing issue in auto generate code ? In which place i need to configure this http handler ?

Comment: I would first try if you don't use the auto-generated code but use what is offerred in the duplicate works. If that is the case then your real question is: How can I make the code generator I use apply the needed HttpClientHandler which sounds a bit more answerable. Ping if you figured out what is needed because based on that I might have to re-open this again.

Comment: @yaakov that is true. Then it is unclear where the issue originates

Comment: @ The issue originates at auto-generated code as newtonsoft json cannot deserialize the content(as content in zipped format). So that is my question how can we support gZip functionality in this case ? Also where we should configure the httpclienthandler ?